# Image fails to render after successful fetch in React native

Tags: image, react-native, render

I'm attempting to render an image that is the result of a successful fetch.

It seems fairly simple and everything works, except the picture fails to render.

In my constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const deliveryManPic = Config.images.deliveryManPic;

        this.state = {
            callModal: false,
            beepModal: false,
            pictureForBackground: null,
            finished: deliveryManPic,
            secondPic: null,

        };
        this.batteryLevelIndicator = '';
        this.pictureUrl = 'someURL';
    }
```

In my ComponentWillMount:

```
componentWillMount() {
        const urlForPicture = this.pictureUrl;
        apiService.getPicture(urlForPicture, (res) => {
            if (res !== null) {
                // console.log('here is your response', res);
                this.setState({ pictureForBackground: res, });
            } else {
                loggingService.debug('theres been a problem');
            }
        });
    }
```

Finally, inside my render method:

```
<View style={styles.deliveryGuyView}>
                        <Image
                            resizeMode="cover"
                            style={styles.policeCarIcon}
                            defaultSource={{ uri: this.state.finished }}
                            source={{ uri: this.state.pictureForBackground }}
                            onLoadEnd={() => {
                                console.log('pic has finished loading');
                            }}
                        />
                    </View>
```

I don't see any yellow messages or errors in the console.log, but I don't see the picture that was successfully fetched.  What could be the reason the picture fails to render?

Comment: Can you show the uri of the photo, as well as the style for styles.policeCarIcon? If height and width are not given in the styles, then that can be an issue.

Comment: Sorry, I responded to a previous user about a minute ago...The responder then deleted his answer that contained my answer/response.   I forgot to add the height and width for policeCarIcon.  I'll try to update this post immediately. Thank you for responding.  You definitely knew what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add the height and width inside the PoliceCarIcon styles object.